# How to play ogg Vorbis files using IGraphBuilder

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-7, oggvorbis

I need to write a program that can play .ogg Vorbis file with the help of IGraphBuilder or any other windows API directly (in C++/win32 API)?

I tried with IGraphBuilder but that is not working for me.
Sample code:

```
IMediaControl *pControl = NULL;
IGraphBuilder *pGraph= NULL;
IMediaEventEx *pEvent= NULL;
IMediaPosition *pMediaPosition= NULL;

hr = ::CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FilterGraph, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                        IID_IGraphBuilder, (void **)&pGraph);
if (FAILED(hr)) {
    return false;
}

hr = pGraph->AddFilter(pFilter, L"Out");
hr = pGraph->QueryInterface(IID_IMediaControl, (void **)&pControl);
hr = pGraph->QueryInterface(IID_IMediaEvent, (void **)&pEvent);
hr = pGraph->QueryInterface(IID_IMediaPosition, (void**)&pMediaPosition);

// Build the graph.
hr = pGraph->RenderFile(mFilePath.c_str()/*"C:\\sample.ogg file"*/, NULL);

/* here hr = 0x80040265 so SUCCEEDED(hr) didnt allow it to enter in if condition*/
if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
    // Run the graph.
    hr = pControl->Run();
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        // Wait for completion.
        long evCode;
        pEvent->WaitForCompletion(INFINITE, &evCode);
    }
}

// Clean up in reverse order.
SAFE_RELEASE(pEvent);
SAFE_RELEASE(pControl);
SAFE_RELEASE(pGraph);
pGraph = NULL;

::CoUninitialize();
```

NOTE:
Above statement `hr = pGraph->RenderFile()` returned the hr = 0x80040265 and condition `if (SUCCEEDED(hr))` doesnt allow to play it.

If I dont use this condition then `pControl->Run()` gets executed with return ID_OK. But nothing played with speaker.
Please suggest the solution/method.

Comment: What does "that is not working for me" mean? Errors? Unicorns dancing? Something else?

Comment: Thanks for response. RenderFile() function returned hr = 0x80040265. I have added the question for more clarity.

Comment: In the case of `IGraphBuilder::RenderFile()`, that HRESULT maps to `VFW_E_UNSUPPORTED_STREAM`, which basically means your setup does not support playing Ogg Vorbis files. You will need to install a filter that allows DirectShow to play Ogg Vorbis files, such as [the official one from Xiph](https://xiph.org/dshow/).

Comment: It is working.. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `0x80040265` is [`VFW_E_UNSUPPORTED_STREAM` "Cannot play back the file.  The format is not supported."](http://alax.info/blog/1383)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pay attention to `HRESULT` error codes; they mean something. MSDN is often helpful with function-specific error codes like the one you got. (With enough COM programming you'll be able to recognize common ones like `E_INVALIDARG` by sight.) If not, you can use your header files to pinpoint potential error codes. `HRESULT`s have a specific format; learn it!

In the case of [`IGraphBuilder::RenderFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390090%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), that `HRESULT` maps to `VFW_E_UNSUPPORTED_STREAM`, which basically means your setup does not support playing Ogg Vorbis files. You will need to install a filter that allows DirectShow to play Ogg Vorbis files, such as [the official one from Xiph.Org](https://xiph.org/dshow/).